# IOException : When Executing Java File Code in Linux box

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Here is My WriteFile

```
WriteFile.writeFile(str, "./test/my.html");
```

And `writeFile()` method code

```
public static void writeFile(String content, String fileName)
  {
    try
    {
      File file = new File(fileName);
      if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
      }
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
      bw.write(content);
      bw.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This Code Working fine With Windows but in Linux I am getting below exception

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
    at org.sewa.util.WriteFile.writeFile(WriteFile.java:25)
```

Comment: Maybe it's case related. Windows is not case-sensitive, while Linux is.

Comment: I think it should help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469018/cannot-make-file-java-io-ioexception-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: @broncoAbierto Windows is not case-sensitive *by default*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Behavior of `createNewFile` is the same in Windows and Linux, so most likely the path of the file you're specifing exists in Windows while it does not in Linux. In your example, `test/` directory does not exist in Linux in the directory where you're executing the program. If you want to create the whole path, see [File#mkdirs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29).