# No such file or directory on bolts

Tags: java, apache-storm

Sometimes I see the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947) ~[na:1.7.0_11]
        at backtype.storm.util$touch.invoke(util.clj:442) ~[storm-core-0.9.0-wip17.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$eval4389$exec_fn__1048__auto____4390.invoke(worker.clj:337) ~[na:na]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:185) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) [clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:601) ~[clojure-1.4.0.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$eval4389$mk_worker__4445.doInvoke(worker.clj:329) [na:na]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512)
```

on bolt startup.

From the launcher, everything seems fine (it tells me that the topology was submitted correctly). However, when I'm trying to read the logs in the bolt, I see the above exception.

Another weird thing - I can see the exception, only when I have 2 topologies I created up and running (the topologies have different name, and their bolts are not identical (meaning - some bolts are the same, some aren't)

Do you know what is the source of it?

Comment: The answers are probably right: it's not a Storm specific issue but just a problem with one of your topologies looking for a file or directory that isn't there.

Comment: did you get any solution ? !!

Answer (score 0):

Check the filename/directory that you are dealing with. Great chances that you have a typo in the filename or in the path.

Check also the permissions of the filename/directory. Maybe you don't have the right permissions.

Comment: The weird thing is, when I deploy only one of the topolgies, it works fine. Only deploying then both results with exception

Comment: just to be sure - the excpetion I get is not for any file I'm looking for, it's from the storm itself

Comment: @user3289736 You are deploying the same topology twice! :|

Comment: i've same error but i deployed topology only one time

Answer (score 0):

It means that your assumptions and expectations is not matching.
Check your path that will help you and by the way many sites are here just google, for e.g

[Cannot make file java.io.IOException: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469018/cannot-make-file-java-io-ioexception-no-such-file-or-directory)

http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2013/05/javaioioexception-no-such-file-or.html

https://community.oracle.com/message/9111592

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=232653

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=192790

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/76705/java-io-ioexception-no-such-file-or-directory-while-trying-to-back-up

and blah! blah! ..just Google once :)