# Firebase Storage download file IO exception

Tags: android, file, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to download a file to my local storage, everything was working untill I added another class and bundled both together in an IFormattable interface.

What I want to do is to first check wether I allready have the file on my memory and if not, download it. In either case I bind it to an imageview.

```
public void setDrawable(Context context, IFormattable item, ImageView binding)
    {
        File file = localStorageHelper.getImageFile(item);
        if(file.length() > 0)
        {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(file)
                    .into(binding);
        }
        else
        {
            StorageReference fileRef = storageRef.child(item.formatImageFile());
            fileRef.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Glide.with(context)
                            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                            .load(firebaseStorage.getReference(item.formatImageFile()))
                            .into(binding);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I now all of the sudden get this error:

```
E/FileDownloadTask: Exception occurred during file write.  Aborting.
                    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
                        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1000)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source:75)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source:190)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source:2)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
E/StorageException: No such file or directory
                    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
                        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1000)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source:75)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source:190)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source:2)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
E/StorageException: No such file or directory
                    java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:281)
                        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1000)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source:75)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.FileDownloadTask.run(Unknown Source:190)
                        at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source:2)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
```

I have no idea what the problem exactly is, the error description is too vague. What I am certain of is that the file does exist and that the path is correct.

Comment: The most likely cause is that the directory that you try to create the file in doesn't exist. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469018/cannot-make-file-java-io-ioexception-no-such-file-or-directory) or some of the other [pages about this exact stack trace](https://www.google.com/search?q=java.io.File.createNewFile+java.io.IOException%3A+No+such+file+or+directory).

Answer (score 1):

The problem i think is you are running this on a phone with API Level 26+ and from 26+ onwards you have to ask for the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission explicitly, only asking for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE wont work. Read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787577/unable-to-save-image-file-in-android-oreo-update-how-to-do-it/47788508#47788508) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had first to create the file, it seems that if there is no directory made before, there will be an error.
So in **FLutter**, I had to do this:

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
File downloadToFile = File(
              '${appDocDir.path}/myPath/myFile.txt');
await downloadToFile.create(recursive: true);
await FirebaseStorage.instance
                .ref("downloadPath")
                .writeToFile(downloadToFile);
```

Here is the thing that **recursive** parameters created the directory for me, that is the thing that did solve the problem for me.

I know that the flutter code is not what the OP is asking for but it's here for demonstration so that anyone can convert it to his needed language.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, in my case I was able to download certain files such as small text files, but large files brought the exception.

**Solution:**

I replaced `.getFile()` to [getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) since `getFile` downloads directly to the device