# Write file to getFilesDir() fails - NoSuchElementException

Tags: android, file, fileinputstream, filewriter

here is what I am doing :

1- Getting a file from my assests and put it into a String - SUCCESSFUL

2- Make A file in `getFilesDir()` - FAILS (No crash yet)

3- Write the string I got to this file using a `FileWriter` - FAILS (No crash yet)

4- Read the new File that I have just made - FAILS (throws NoSuchElementException)

Here are the stuff you gotta see :

A small useful method which i used :

```
public String inputStreamToString(InputStream stream){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
        String aa = s.next();
        return aa;

    }
```

Snippet of MainActivity.java :

```
//B2 and text are a well defined Button and TextView respectively, ensured through previous testings
B2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AssetManager as = getAssets();
                InputStream stream = null;
                try {
                    stream = as.open("updater-script");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
                String aa = s.next();
                text.setText(aa);

                File file = new File(getFilesDir() + "/updater-script");
                try {
                    boolean b = file.createNewFile(); //returns false, indicating the file wasn't made
                    text.setText(text.getText()+String.valueOf(b));
                    new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()).mkdirs();
                    FileWriter write = new FileWriter(getFilesDir().toString()+File.pathSeparator+"updater-script");
                    Show(getFilesDir().toString());
                    write.write(aa);
                    write.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
        });
        B2.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "updater-script");
                try {
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                    String aa = inputStreamToString(in);
                    text.setText(aa);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return true;
            }
        });
```

My Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="seaskyways.testingproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="beta" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STROAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <activity
            android:name="seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="seaskyways.testingproject.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="seaskyways.testingproject.Splash"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="seaskyways.testingproject.HorizontalScrollView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HSV" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="seaskyways.testingproject.ExpandableLists"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_expandable_lists"
            android:parentActivityName="seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="seaskyways.testingproject.SwipeStrips"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_swipe_tabs"
            android:parentActivityName="seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="seaskyways.testingproject.SwipeTabs"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_swipe_tabs"
            android:parentActivityName="seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Stack Trace :

```
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958): java.util.NoSuchElementException
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1007)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:980)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity.inputStreamToString(MainActivity.java:44)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at seaskyways.testingproject.MainActivity$7.onLongClick(MainActivity.java:171)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4240)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8060)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:17339)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-11 21:23:08.241: E/AndroidRuntime(3958):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please no workarounds , because I have future plans ... Thanks for any help ! If you need any more info am here , and the comment box is a few centimeters down :P

Comment: Your logcat is actually suggesting your error is at s.next();

Comment: **boolean b = file.createNewFile(); //returns false, indicating the file wasn't made** - Read the docs for `createNewFile()` http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createNewFile() If the file can't be created, it will throw an `IOException`. If you're getting `false` as a return on the call and no exception then it's because the file already exists.

Comment: or, like my amended answer indicates, because the permissions are slightly wrong...

Comment: @DigCamara : `getFilesDir()` returns a path on the internal storage so  permissions for writing to the external storage are not required. But you are correct about the typo in the manifest.

Comment: Well, if the last suggestion fails, I'll leave this question with the advice someone else gave someone who also couldn't create files using those instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525060/file-createnewfile-thowing-ioexception-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: It seems to me just using `openFileOutput(...)` and `openFileInput(...)` would make most sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25984/discussion-between-digcamara-and-squonk)

Comment: @Squonk , yes , I went to the directory where the file should be (as root) , and I found my file (updater-script) there with 0kb size , this leaves that the problem is in writing to the file ... For the record , I decompiled some app that uses the functionality i need (using a specialized decompiler from apk to source) , it doesn't use any permission to write a file to getFilesDir() , it does it plainly ! I will see your suggestion Squonk ! Thanks for help guys !

Comment: @Squonk , nop , openFileInput doesn't take path seperators , which will throw an IllegalArguementException ...

Comment: @Seaskyways : **"nop , openFileInput doesn't take path seperators "** - Yes, I know that. Don't use a path separator just use the filename. The whole point about `openFileInput(...)` and `openFileOutput(...)` is they are helper methods which abstract the need to know anything about a file's path and the directory it is read from / written to.

Answer (score 1):

From [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) I understand that you should actually protect your .next() invocations with [.hasNext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29).

Here, for instance:

```
public String inputStreamToString(InputStream stream){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
    if (s.hasNext()){
       return s.next();
    }else{
       return null;
    }       
}
```

And, if your permissions are written correctly, this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STROAGE"/>
```

permission doesn't actually exist. It should be

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: If you read what I wrote well , you should have known that my stack trace points to my `s.next()` because `boolean b =file.createNewFile();` return false , indicating the file wasn't created , meaning that my scanner won't find any "next()" , causing an exception ... This isn't an answer , this will cause me to have a NullPointerException ...

Comment: You're right. And I added a new section to my answer, which might actually explain why you don't have rights to create a file. If that doesn't do the trick, I'll gladly withdraw my answer.

Comment: You might have to clean the project and reinstall it. Eclipse is not very good at detecting changes made to the Manifest (if you're using Eclipse, of course)

Answer (score 0):

I said :" boolean b = file.createNewFile(); //returns false, indicating the file wasn't made "
which isn't true , b = false without any exceptions means that the file is already made ... But the crash was caused because the File that was created doesn't have any text to be read , which will , yea , cause a crash , since am reading nothing ...

So to correct it , I don't need any permissions , just Java ... All I have to do is either write something to that file before trying to read it or program my class which gives me a `String` of an `InputStream` to return something instead of nothing and crashing :

So the first solution is like this :

```
File file = new File(get_data_dir(getApplicationContext()), "updater-script");
                try {

                    InputStream stream = null;
                    try {
                        stream = getAssets().open("updater-script");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    FileOutputStream ou = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    byte[] buffer = inputStreamToString(stream).getBytes();
                    ou.write(buffer);//Now the file has something to be read ...


                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);



                    String aa = inputStreamToString(in);
```

And the second Solution which seems to be easier is this :

```
public String inputStreamToString(InputStream stream){
        String aa;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
        if(s.hasNext()){
            aa = s.next();
        }else{
            aa = "";
        }

        return aa;//Now it returns something no matter what ...

    }
```