# Cannot write file to Documents folder

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to write to a file in Java, or create a new file if the file doesn't exist. (Using JDK 14). However, when I run the following code I get an IOException at the if statement condition that reads `The system could not find the file specified` if the file doesn't exist, and `Access is denied` if the file does.

```
File file = new File(filePath);
System.out.println(filePath); // C:\Users\username\Documents\test.txt
if (file.createNewFile()) {
    System.out.println("File successfully created");
} else {
    System.out.println("File already exists");
}
```

The code works when I attempt to save it to the desktop folder and saves the file successfully, but for whatever reason isn't allowed to touch Documents.

The user I'm running IntelliJ as has full access to all files on the computer, and running the IDE as administrator did not fix the problem. However, I can save to the user folder and the desktop. It is only Documents or child directories of it that I can't save to.

There are a few similar questions on the site such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525060/file-createnewfile-thowing-ioexception-no-such-file-or-directory), however the cause is not the same as in my case this is a permissions issue, and not an issue of a missing directory.

Comment: I'm getting filePath from a JFileChooser instance. I'm confident the string format is not the issue as the file chooser is able to select and save to a file on the desktop without error.

Comment: How are you getting the selected file from the JFileChooser? Its `chooser.getSelectedFile()` will return a `File` object so your `new File(filePath)` wouldn't be needed, which is throwing me off. (but really this should make no difference since it's working for you saving to the desktop)

Comment: If the user doesn't specify an extension the filePath doesn't include one so I have to add it on manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just hit this same issue. It seems that JFileChooser() on some Windows 10 installations doesn't tell the os that the user has selected a folder and as such Sandboxing, Malware Control, Access control blocks access to create a file even though the user had full access (permission checks are OK but file write fails with IOException 13 or Access Denied). However FileDialog() DOES work where JFileChooser fails...

Comment: Seems to work, however FileDialog is missing some features of JFileChooser like support for filename filters (the current implementation apparently doesn't work on Windows).

Answer (score -2):

- 1

if you want write data to file just user any `Writer` For example:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(yourFile);
```

You can use stream filtering for faster action.
Show more your code. You've just showed condition for existing file.

- 2

if you want create file in Documents folder, get a path, then make a:

`File file = new File(documentPath);`

```
while(!file.exists())
    file.createNewFile();
//condition for file existing...`
```

If I don't help, comment below, just I can't understand your question :). Good Luck